# Get the JSON response from a Cron Job response

Tags: javascript, cron, jobs

I am calling a Cron Job and work fine, but I have an application need to call the Cron Job, my app use the URL and my app start the cron job but I want to get the JSON RESPONSE to record the final status, like this

`{"status":403,"message":"Export #23 is currently in manually process. Request skipped."}`

This is the response in the browser its a simple JSON but I can't get the result, this is the code

```
function Export() {
    var uri = "https://originalURL.com/wp-load.php?export_key=s4DdYEDQ4DOC2222&export_id=23&action=trigger"

    fetch(uri, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            alert(data.message);
        }).catch(err => alert(err))
}
```

The cron start OK but i need to get the response to record a historial in my database !

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to a file that saves the response in a database or text file on the server-side. An example of this would be

**getData.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var response = {"This is my response key":"This is my response value", "This is another key":"This is another value"};
      $.get("saveData.php", {response: response});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**saveData.php**

```
<?php
  $response = $_GET['response'];
  file_put_contents('responseText.txt',$response);
?>
```

Here, getData.html gets the response data (from the variable response), sends a request to saveData.php with the response data, and saveData.php puts the response into responseText.txt, which you can later extract from.

Comment: Sorry i dont get it... my app call a URL and the URL return a json

Comment: @FernandoZamudio Yes, your app calls a URL and you want to store the response somewhere. For you to do that, you must make a connection to your database, which can only be done with certain languages. Specifically, server-side languages can make connections like that. The language you wrote your code in can't. You can either call another file with a language that can connect to your database (ex. PHP), or you can change your code entirely to be a server-side language (ex. PHP).